# C# key pressed listener in a Windows Forms UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, keylistener

Good day,

I want to add key listeners in a forms user control. Which is included in a main form.

When a user presses a key in my application I want it to do some thing.

How do I go about doing this?

for example.  If I pressed w then a popup would appear saying you pressed w.

I have tried this in my User Control Class;

```
  private void UC_ControlsTank_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("You pressed:" + e.KeyChar);
    }
```

But when i press keys nothing seems to happen.

EDIT:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is my form:
and here is how I linked it in visual studio:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean UserControl as one in a Windows Forms application, or an ASP.NET UserControl ?

Comment: Does your control have focus?

Comment: @IvayloSlavov Windows Forms

Answer (score 13):

First of all before capturing KeyPress you have to set the `KeyPreview` property of the Win Form to `true`. Unless you set it to true KeyPress will not be captured.

Comment: Click on the WinForm and press F4 which will show the properties window, There set the KeyPreview to true. by default its set to false.

Comment: Also, this should be set if you're trying to catch a key pressed on other control than form itself(i.e. TextBox)

Answer (score 5):

There is a `KeyPressed` event that you can use

[Control.KeyPress Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)

This has `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e` that will tell you what key was pressed

Edit:

So I just tried this on a sample app and it worked fine

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Will that not only work in the console? or will it also work in my windows form?

Comment: Cant even get wither of these solutions working in the main form:

Comment: How are you hooking the event up? I have update my answer with what I did and it works. Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: I just create a temp project and it worked as well. now i went back and tried again in the project im working on (in the main form not the UC) and it didnt work, which is odd? See my edit

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: What i have done is in the main form I Setup the key press event, and I then just forward the event to the user control by calling its keypressed event.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an Example ,

```
  private void control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.W:
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("you pressed w");
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.B:
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("you pressed b");
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.F11:
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("you pressed F11");
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.Escape:
                {
                    this.Close();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
}
```

**or**

Reference this [Overriding Keydown in a User Control using ProcessKeyPreview](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22570/Overriding-Keydown-in-a-User-Control-using-Process) .

Comment: I Tried this, But again . Nothing appears

Comment: unfortunately , usercontrol doesn't have `KeyPreview` Property I think. See my edit . This Link will help you !

Comment: Surely there is a simpler way than using ProcessKeyPreview